# Append data after xpath using jquery

Tags: javascript, jquery, html, xpath

How to append data after xpath like `/html/body/div[1]/section/div[2]/div[2]/div/div/div[2]/div/form/div[1]/div[4]/div/div` in jquery.

I am able to append using php but i want in jquery.

Comment: You can use [jquery-xpath](https://github.com/ilinsky/jquery-xpath) if you want to use xpath. But in pure jquery, you need to convert it to selector. For example like `$("body > div:first > section > div:eq(1) ...")`

Answer (score 0):

**With jQuery**

Simple and clean... lets make a nice function that :

Converts the xPath to jQuery Sellector, gets the element using jQuery and then returns it.

```
// Get an element by xpath
// Using jQuery
function getJQueryElementByXpath(xpath){
    var selector;

    // Remove any '/' on the beginning of the string
    // ex "/html/div" -> "html/div"
    selector = xpath.replace(/^\s*\/\s*/g, "");

    // Convert '/' to ' > ' to express child search
    selector = selector.replace(/\s*\/\s*/g, " > ");

    // Convert '[number]' to ':eq(number)'
    selector = selector.replace(/\[(\d+)\]/g, ":eq($1)");

    // Return the jQuery element
    return jQuery(selector);
}
```

And now you can get your element and append what ever you want on it.

```
// My xpath
var xpath = "/html/body/div[1]/section/div[2]/div[2]/div/div/div[2]/div/form/div[1]/div[4]/div/div";

// Get the element with jQuery
var myXpathElement = getJQueryElementByXpath(xpath);

// Lets append an other element
myXpathElement.append(exampleElement);
```

---

**Without jQuery**

And if you don't want to use jQuery, using only javascript on a modern browser

(Chrome 4.0, Internet Explorer 9.0, Firefox 3.5, Safari 3.2, Opera 10.0 or later, reference http://caniuse.com/#feat=queryselector)

```
// Get an element by xpath
// Using Javascript (on modern browsers)
// Need support for document.querySelector using css3
function getElementByXpath(xpath){
    var selector;

    // Remove any '/' on the beginning of the string
    // ex "/html/div" -> "html/div"
    selector = xpath.replace(/^\s*\/\s*/g, "");

    // Convert '/' to ' > ' to express child search
    selector = selector.replace(/\s*\/\s*/g, " > ");

    // Convert '[number]' to ':nth-of-type(number+1)'
    selector = selector.replace(/\[(\d+)\]/g, function(n){ return ":nth-of-type(" + (++n[1]) + ")" });

    // Return the javascript element
    return document.querySelector(selector);
}
```